# How to add elements to specific index conditionaly?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I want to add an element to specific index when a certain attribute changes compared to the previous one.

We have:

```
const arr = [
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 3 },
  { num: 3 },
  { num: 4 },
  { num: 5 },
];
```

I want it to become

```
const arr = [
  { separator:true }
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 1 },
  { separator:true }
  { num: 3 },
  { num: 3 },
  { separator:true }
  { num: 4 },
  { separator:true }
  { num: 5 },
];
```

I did this:

```
const getIndexes = (myArr) => {
  let indexes = [];
  let previousValue = null;
  myArr.forEach((el, idx) => {
    if (el.num !== previousValue) {
      indexes.push(idx);
      previousValue = el.num;
    }
  });
  return indexes;
};

const insertSeparator = (arr) => {
  let result = arr;
  getIndexes(arr).forEach((position) => result.splice(position, 0, { separator: true }));
  return result
};
```

and it returns:

```
[
  { separator: true },
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 1 },
  { separator: true },
  { num: 1 },
  { separator: true },
  { separator: true },
  { num: 3 },
  { num: 3 },
  { num: 4 },
  { num: 5 }
]
```

Maybe because of the "new" size of the array, because it is getting bigger and changes its dimension.

What do you think is the best way to solve this?

Comment: The splice is changing the indexes. Instead of doing it in two stages just push in your initial loop. Here using `flatMap()`. `const result = arr.flatMap((o, i, { [i - 1]: prev }) => o.num !== prev?.num ? [{ separator: true }, o] : o);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it through `.flatMap()`

```
const result = arr.flatMap((obj, idx, arr) => {...
```

`.flatMap()` is `.map()` and `.flat()` combined, so it transforms the contents of a copy of the given array and removes the brackets `[]`. Next, we return the first object with a separator:

```
if (idx == 0) {
  // returns are wrapped in brackets because they'll be removed before being returned
  return [{separator: true}, obj]; 
}
```

The next step is to compare the current value with the previous value:

```
obj.num == arr[idx - 1].num ? // current value vs previous value
[arr[idx - 1]] : // if they are the same value return previous value
[{separator: true}, obj]; /* if they are not the same then return that separator 
and current */
```

```js
const arr = [
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 3 },
  { num: 3 },
  { num: 4 },
  { num: 5 },
];

const result = arr.flatMap((obj, idx, arr) => {
  if (idx == 0) {
    return [{
      separator: true
    }, obj];
  }
  return obj.num == arr[idx - 1].num ? [arr[idx - 1]] : [{
    separator: true
  }, obj];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose this solution which would consume only one iteration with a reduce :

```js
const arr = [{
    num: 1
  },
  {
    num: 1
  },
  {
    num: 1
  },
  {
    num: 3
  },
  {
    num: 3
  },
  {
    num: 4
  },
  {
    num: 5
  },
];


let prev_value = arr[0];
const result = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const insert = (val.num !== prev_value.num) ? [{
    separator: true
  }, val] : [val];
  prev_value = val;
  return acc.concat(insert)
}, [{
  separator: true
}, ])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be other ways to do it too. But with a simple modification to your code it can be done. You just need to keep track of the offset with a new variable, incrementing it in the loop:

```js
const arr = [
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 1 },
  { num: 3 },
  { num: 3 },
  { num: 4 },
  { num: 5 },
];

const getIndexes = (myArr) => {
  let indexes = [];
  let previousValue = null;
  myArr.forEach((el, idx) => {
    if (el.num !== previousValue) {
      indexes.push(idx);
      previousValue = el.num;
    }
  });
  return indexes;
};

const insertSeparator = (arr) => {
  let result = [...arr];
  let offset = -1;
  getIndexes(arr).forEach((position) => { 
offset++;  
return result.splice(position+offset, 0, { separator: true });
});

return result
};

console.log(insertSeparator(arr));
```

**Note:** If you want to start with `0` you can do the increment in the `.splice()` itself : `result.splice(position+(offset++),`

Answer (score 1):

```
const positions = [];
//arr.sort((a, b) => a.num - b.num); You can uncomment this line to ensure that the array will always sorted based on num property
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index < arr.length - 1 && item.num != arr[index + 1].num) {
    positions.push(index + 1);
  }
});

let counter = 0;
positions.forEach((pos) => {
  arr.splice(pos + counter++, 0, { separator: true });
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to:

1. Do something which each item in a list
2. Want to return something other than a list of the same size.

Then I would suggest the good all-round [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.

```
const separator = {separator: true};
arr.reduce((result, item) => {
  if (result.at(-1)?.num === item.num) {
    return [...result, separator, item];
  }

 return [...result, item]
}, [])
```

This is (according to me) easier, cleaner and safer since it doesn't mutate variables.

---

#### Note

[Array.prototype.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) is at the time of writing a new function. If you are using an ancient browser that doesn't support it you can use `arr[arr.length -1]` to get the last item instead.